# Amazon Keyspace maximum table partition size

Tags: database, cassandra, amazon-keyspaces

Is there a maximum size limit to a table partition in Amazon Keyspaces?
I want to store around 110 TB of unstructured data and I'm trying to choose between manually sharding DocumentDB due to its collection size limit. I'd take up keyspaces if it doesn't have a partition size limit.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the total amount per table partition is [2 billion cells.](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/stable/cassandra/data_modeling/data_modeling_refining.html)

I know that this is an apache doc, not an AWS one, but I've found them to be relatively similar